# Excluding Care of Magical Creatures, what were Hagrid's magical strengths?

Tags: harry-potter

Hagrid is obviously gifted with magical creatures, but do we know if he has any other particular magical talents, taking into consideration that he only completed three years at Hogwarts? I think that Hagrid demonstrates with his pink umbrella/broken wand that he's basically competent at rudimentary charms. Perhaps his knowledge of the Forbidden Forest would lend his skill to potions or herbology?

**What else was Hagrid skilled in besides Care of Magical Creatures?**

Comment: Well we know he was skilled in Wizarding Distillery.

Comment: He did know how to tear up a bender, that's for sure :)

Comment: Not strictly a magical strength per se, but when in doubt he was big enough that he could "jog" someone's memory hard enough to get them out of his way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While Hagrid is obviously not a Wizard at the same level as Hermione or Harry, we do see that he is capable of using magic effectively.

- In *Philosopher's Stone*, we see him use Transfiguration magic on Dudley Dursley at the Hut-on-a-Rock.
- We see him using various Charms during the course of the series: one of his own invention on both the boats the First years ride, and the one he and Harry ride to the mainland from the Hut-on-a-Rock in, and he uses *Engorgio* on his giant pumpkins.
- In *Philosopher's Stone*, he claimed to have flown in to the Hut-on-a-Rock, however we do not see his motorcycle outside after he and Harry leave. Hagrid cannot use brooms, so it is likely that if he did fly there, he did it unaided. In the [Pottermore article on Vernon and Petunia Dursley](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vernon-and-petunia-dursley), J. K. Rowling writes about Petunia: "she had frequently seen Lily jump streams and run across stepping stones in their childhood, she ought not to have been surprised when Hagrid had no difficulty making his way over the stormy sea to the hut on the rock." If Hagrid did indeed walk or jump across the water, that would be impressive magic in its own right.
- He used nonverbal magic frequently, as he was not strictly allowed to use magic. This aided him by making it harder to catch him using magic.
- He conjured fire in the Hut-on-a-Rock during *Philosopher's Stone*, and water in *Order of the Phoenix* to put out the fires in his hut after the Battle of the Astronomy Tower.
- It must be considered that *all* of Hagrid's magic may have been effectively wandless magic, if his wand was still broken. We do not see any other wand performing as effectively as Hagrid's "broken" wand during the course of the series.
- It could be safely assumed that Hagrid has some skill at brewing potions as well. We see him shopping for potion ingredients and administering various concoctions to his pets/the plants on the grounds.
- Likewise, it could also be assumed that Hagrid had aptitude for Herbology. In *Chamber of Secrets* we are told that part of his responsibilities as the Keeper of Keys and Grounds was to look after the various flora that grew on Hogwarts. That would require a decent level of practical knowledge in Herbology, considering the kind of flora that grew at Hogwarts.

Hagrid's main strength did lie in Care of Magical Creatures, however. The creatures he successfully raised were fearsome and dangerous, yet they never gave Hagrid much trouble. That in of itself shows a considerable aptitude towards a very specialized field of magic.

Comment: You know, it's really interesting, but JKR suggested on Pottermore that Hagrid might have walked across the water to get to the hut on the rock, to give Harry his letter. I thought that was kind of a new bombshell-like bit of info. :)

Comment: I do remember that. Not sure how, but it's sort of impressive magic in its own right. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Don't forget the giant pumpkins!

Comment: Flight seems unlikely. IIRC Voldemort being able to fly unaided was surprising to people, though I don't have the exact quote on that.

Answer (score 3):

+100 vs. spell damage `</roleplaying_geek>`

I am not aware of canon evidence for any actual special *magical* skills aside from affinity to magical creatures (I'm not saying that he can not use magic - he can - but he has no great skill at it).

From JKR interview:

> He has been allowed to do magic openly ever since he became a teacher but because he was never fully trained **his magic is never going to be what it should be. He is always going to be a bit inept** ([src](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-swns-alfie.htm)).

However, being a Creatures guy (as well as resident Forest Ranger), he most likely logically had to possess at least rudimentary medical/FirstAid/**veterinary** skills. I don't recall canon evidence for or against those including potion making.

Comment: Don't forget apparent crossbow skills.

Comment: First aid skills?  I seem to remember he mentioned somewhere in *Stone* that unicorn tail hairs are very strong and good for bandages.